# Subprocess loop in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a folder with a few hundred .bed files that I want to loop over to extract fasta sequences. In the terminal, my command is:

```
twoBitToFa -bed=PA2_03_2bit.bed -udcDir=. https://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.2bit stdout > PA2_03.fa
```

This works for the single bed file, but I'd rather not do this several hundred times.

I'm new to subprocesses and python, but this seems like it might be an option. I am open to other options.

So far I have:

```
import os
path_of_the_directory= '/home/2bit_L1_beds'
for filename in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    f = os.path.join(path_of_the_directory,filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f)
```

which outputs the path to each file in the directory. To add the sub process, I tried:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

path_of_the_directory= '/home/2bit_L1_beds'
for filename in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    f = os.path.join(path_of_the_directory,filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        result = subprocess.run([twoBitToFa -bed=f -udcDir=. https://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.2bit stdout > f.fa],
                                capture_output=True, text=True)
        print(stdout)
        print(f)
```

I am getting "invalid syntax" and would appreciate some help! My goal is to have 1 .fa file output for each .bed file input.

Comment: The issue is you can either pass a string, or a list of strings to `subprocess.run`. This is because Python expects anything like `[...]` to be a list of elements, where the variables are evaluated. This means stuff like `twoBitToFa` isn't the actual name of the command you're invoking, but it's expecting a variable named `twoBitToFa` which it's gonna use the value of. The characters `>`, `=`, and `.`, and more are where you're getting an invalid syntax error.

Comment: You probably want a command like `subprocess.run('twoBitToFa -bed=f -udcDir=. https://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.2bit stdout > f.fa', shell=True)`, since you need the shell to ensure stuff like `>` properly redirects to the file.

Comment: Thanks! This code does print the list of file names, so the loop works, but the twobittofa command isn't actually working. The output is a blank f.fa file. Ideally, I'd like to end up with 1 .fa file for each .bed file.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't actually fixing the logic of the shell command, just getting you to learn what was wrong in the actual Python syntax. There's a few issues here: 1). You're not providing the actual file `f` to the command, just the string `"f"`. Also, you're always writing to `f.fa`, not something linked to the file name. This is why it's just writing an empty file: the stdout (standard, not error, output) is empty.

Comment: If you actually want the above code to fully work, you probably want something like: `subprocess.run(f'twoBitToFa -bed="{f}" -udcDir=. https://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.2bit stdout > "{os.path.basename(f)}".fa', shell=True)`. This does uses format string literals, where `{f}` is replaced by the value of the variable `f`. I've quoted it in case any spaces or other characters are in it. Next, you want to write to a file based on the name of `f`, and we use `basename` to ensure there's no directories in it.

Comment: Does that make sense? If it's all good, I'm happy to reply with an answer, it's just a few of these individual issues I felt weren't really an answer and have been likely duplicated before. But just marking it as a duplicate doesn't really help you, so I felt I'd ensure you understand how this works first. By the way, to use `os.path.basename`, you need to write `import os.path`, for access to that function.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your time and clear explanations. You are an angel!

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`subprocess.Popen`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) (which you import but do not use) and pass a list of command and arguments. In fact, you can even use `cwd` to change directory to path of files for relative referencing. Below assumes all files end with `_2bit.bed` to be replaced with `.fa`.

```py
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

path_of_the_directory = "/home/mrsmeta/Axiotl/2bit_L1_beds"
url = "https://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.2bit"

for f in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f)

        cmd = [
            "twoBitToFa", f"-bed={f}", "-udcDir=.", url, 
            "stdout", ">", f.replace("_2bit.bed", ".fa")
        ]

        result = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd=path_of_the_directory
        )

        output, error = result.communicate()
        print(output)
```